# How to create Bilevel Partition using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to **d3** world. I am trying to learn it from http://d3js.org/. 
I am trying to create a Bilevel Partition.

[image]

I couldn't get it to display any result. Here is my

### [`JSfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/rzdgepLb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line here:

```
d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json", function(error, root) {
```

This is a call to load a file in on path "/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json". This is not a valid path on the JSFiddle. In the original [code](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371), the path refers to a file hosted on that domain. Note that changing the domain on the Fiddle to the full path ("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json") does not work because JSFiddle protects against cross-site scripting attacks.

Note that you can use debug console on your browser to debug these kinds of errors.

Comment: I didn't know that we can use debug console on the JS Fiddle. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: So how do you add the data to the page and make it work. Thats why doesn't make sense to me.